# How to add viewPager scrolling animation when closing a viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, animation, android-viewpager

I have  view pager inside activity.

I want to implement page scrolling animation when closing a view pager.What I tried was ,when I click close button in viewPager

I'am programatically change the viewPager to the previous position and make a thread to remove the item at next position and updating the adapter.Hope you understand my idea.

How to implement viewPager scrolling animation when click the close button in a viewPager.Thank you in advance

here is my code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_day, container, false);
    cls = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.cls);

    cls.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, true);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ActivityX.removeFromVP();
                    }
                }, 400);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

ActivityX

```
public static void removeFromVP() {
    if (App.getInstance().getsDataSet().size() > 1) {
   App.getInstance().getsDataSet().remove(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);

        if (fAdapter != null) {
            fAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    } else {
        App.getInstance().getsDataSet().clear();
    }
}
```